# Appending h1 then unable to manipulate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just getting started with JS so I got a question.

What I would like to accomplish is for me to append a `h1` tag inside a `div` then click on it and trigger an alert.

```
<div id="heading">h1</div>
<div id="canvas"> </div>
        <script>
          $('#heading').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#canvas').append('<h1>test</h1>');
          });
          $('#heading h1').on('click', function(e) {
            alert('foo');
          });
        </script>
```

this is the code I have now. Now the issue as far as I understand is that the javascript code is ran on load - so when the `h1` is added it won't work.

How do you fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements this should help you

Comment: try `$('#canvas').on('click', 'h1', function(e) {` instead